# QLineEdit change border color without changing border style

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I can change the background color of a QLineEdit widget in PyQt4 by doing this:

```
myEditField.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color : green;}")
```

Changing the border color requires me to do something like this:

```
myEditField.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border : 2px solid green;}")
```

This however is undesirable because it also changes the default shape and size of the border, I've tried using border-color instead, but it apparently only works if you have already specified border.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the stylesheet with following values:

```
       border-style: outset;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-color: green;
```